# calculate positional proximity of two multiword exact phrases inside a large text in Python

Tags: python, text, nlp, distance

How to calculate minimum positional distance between two multi-word, exact phrases inside a large text (e.g. an article), by using Python?
Assumption is that there might be multiple occurrences of both phrases.
To avoid miss-understanding, this is not a question about fuzzy string matching, edit distance, word lists etc.This is question about calculating positional proximity/distance between two exact phrases inside a text.

EDIT (modified solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2359945/razzle-shazl):

```
def str_to_raw(s):
    raw_map = {8:r'\b', 7:r'\a', 12:r'\f', 10:r'\n', 13:r'\r', 9:r'\t', 11:r'\v'}
    return r''.join(i if ord(i) > 32 else raw_map.get(ord(i), i) for i in s)

def find_smallest_distance1(sentence, word1, word2):
    distances = []
    dist = float('inf')
    p1 = str_to_raw(word1)
    p2 = str_to_raw(word2)
    s = sentence
    """
    f1 = re.finditer(r'\bred fox\b', s, re.I)
    f2 = re.finditer(r'\bblue hen\b', s, re.I)
    """
    f1 = re.finditer(p1, s, re.I)
    f2 = re.finditer(p2, s, re.I)    
    _f1 = _f2 = None
    while True:
        try:
            _f1 = next(f1)
        except StopIteration:
            break
    
        if _f2 == None:
            try:
                _f2 = next(f2)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            
        if _f1.span()[0] > _f2.span()[0]:
            # we want f1 to always be closer to start / lower start index
            f1, f2 = f2, f1
            _f1, _f2 = _f2, _f1
        
        dist = min(dist, _f2.span()[0] - _f1.span()[1])
    return dist
```

I was wondering, how can it be modified, so that distance of phrase2 (word2) is calculated only to left or only to right direction from position of phrase1 (word1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's **find the indices** for both substrings.  Then we can walk both lists of indices and calculate minimum distance in one pass.

I would use **regular expressions** as they are flexible (think about future maintainers) and powerful.

We create two iterators that return matches for both substrings.  Then we pop the iterator that has the lower value (in this case, lowest start index).

When this "shorter" iterator is finally exhausted, we can skip checking the remainder of the other iterator as those indices will have a worse distance than already obtained.

### Shortest Distance

```
import re

def positionalProximity(re1: str, re2: str, s: str, bidir: bool = True, regexFlags: int = 0) -> int:
    # returns shortest positional distance between re1 and re2
    # when not bidirectional, then search for re1 only to the left of re2
    dist = float('inf')
    f1 = re.finditer(re1, s, regexFlags)
    f2 = re.finditer(re2, s, regexFlags)
    _f1 = _f2 = None
    while True:
        try:
            _f1 = next(f1)
        except StopIteration:
            break

        if _f2 == None:
            try:
                _f2 = next(f2)
            except StopIteration:
                break

        if bidir and _f1.span()[0] > _f2.span()[0]:
            # we want f1 to always be closer to start / lower start index
            f1, f2 = f2, f1
            _f1, _f2 = _f2, _f1

        if bidir or _f2.span()[0] > _f1.span()[1]:
            dist = min(dist, _f2.span()[0] - _f1.span()[1])
    return dist


s = 'The red fox took stock of the blue hen,\
    and the blue hen took stock of the red fox.\
    "Blue hen!" cried red fox.  "Blue hen!"'
re1 = r'\bred fox\b'
re2 = r'\bblue hen\b'

print(f'dist = {positionalProximity(re1, re2, s, False)}')
print(f'dist = {positionalProximity(re1, re2, s, regexFlags = re.I)}')
```

*Output*:

```
dist = 19
dist = 4
```

If you are curious about `span()`, it returns the start-inclusive and end-exclusive indices of your match:

```
print([f.span() for f in f1])
print([f.span() for f in f2])
```

*Output*:

```
(4, 11)
(75, 82)
(105, 112)
(30, 38)
(48, 56)
(88, 96)
(116, 124)
```

Comment: Hi, it is great, it seems it woks pretty good. I have  modified it into a functin accepting strings as parameters. Your solution included in my edited question. I was wondering, how can it be modified, so that distance of phrase2 (word2) is calculated only to left or only to right direction from position of phrase1?

Comment: Hi @zlatko, people do not actually expect the answer in the question.  I think its ok to maybe append with an edit.  Otherwise it short-circuits the whole Question & Answer format of stackoverflow.  (don't worry about reverting anything, everything is good!)

Comment: @zlatko I have updated answer to handle all cases.  Let me know if it works for you.