# Efficiently searching a body of text for a large number of keywords (1000's)

Tags: python, arrays, search, set

I am working on a project where I am required to search short to medium bodies of text (up to 100 in a session) for the existence of 1000's of different keywords (stock market symbols). I am using Python.

Now, I know if I approached this with a simple For Loop, this could take a really long time.

What is the most efficient way to do this? Is there a specific python library that's most advantageous here?

Edit: **More Details about my use case:**

- The bodies of text I am searching are Reddit posts of varying length (let's say upper length is 2000 characters).
- I will be searching approximately 100 - 200 different posts per session.
- I need to check for the existence of 1 or more stock symbols in each post. There are 1000's of stock symbols to search for, and the format they are represented in varies such that I need to check for partial matches (ie. GOOG, and $GOOG both match in the body of text).
- I need to list symbols that were found in a given post.

I hope this provides some clarification.

Thank you.

**Posting Solution Based on Answer:**

Here is the basic code I ended up using to compile the stock symbols into Regex. Note that the symbols were stored in a Python Dict called "self.symbols" - where each key was an exchange, and contained a list of symbols as it's value.

```
#Return the dict of stock symbols
def compileSymbols(self):

    #Will hold compiled symbols
    dict = {}

    #For each exchange in dict, join list of symbols and convert to compiled regex
    for key in self.symbols.keys():
        joinedStr = "|".join(self.symbols[key])
        dict[key] = re.compile(r"{0}".format(joinedStr))
    
    #Save compiled symbols
    self.symbols = dict
```

...Then I used the below code to loop through post text and search for symbols - converting the results to a set and back to a list to remove duplicates:

```
#Check posts for matching symbols
def searchPostsForSymbols(self, posts, symbols):

    for post in posts:
    
        #Used to store matching symbols
        matches = []
    
        for exchng in symbols.keys():
            result = symbols[exchng].findall(post, re.M)
            result = list(set(result))
            if len(result) > 0:
                matches.append((exchng, result))
```

Took seconds to search 1000's of symbols - surprisingly good performance. Thank you Malo for the answer!

Comment: Have you tried with regular expression if it is faster ? And it depends what you want to do when there is a match ? please give more details about your goal and expected result.

Comment: @Malo I have updated my question with additional information. Basically, I need to be able to detect the keywords/symbols in up to 2000 character bodies of text, and list matches.

Comment: This is an interesting problem that you have. *Now, I know if I approached this with a simple For Loop, this could take a really long time.* -- this suggests to me that you have not attempted to solve this.  It would really be beneficial for us and posterity if you could gives us something to bite our teeth into.  If you are unsure of where even to begin, please review the guide on asking a good question here on stackoverflow.  For a starting point, as mentioned, try working with regular expression (or *regex*).

Comment: You might be interested in an answer I posted similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66325181/2359945  Note that solution uses 1 iterator per match, and each iterator traverses entire string, so that is extra work being done that you may or may not care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an example of what you can get with regexp. PLease try and time it if it could be usefull in your case:

```
import re

text = """
This is text with
ThiGOOGs is text with
This is tMICRext with
This is text with
This isGOOG text with
This is text with
"""

c = re.compile(r"STOCK|GOOG|MICR")
r = c.findall(text, re.M)
print(r)
```

Output is:

```
['GOOG', 'MICR', 'GOOG']
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually had incredibly good performance that surprised me... I've updated the question with my solution based on your answer.

Comment: Nice to know it was usefull. If you manage to use the re.compile(...) statement, and use it only once out of the loop (and keep always the same symbol list). If you compile once, you may even speed the process a bit more.